# Go fullscreen on button click

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

I would like to have a button that onclick makes the page go fullscreen (as in emulating an `F11` press)

For example:

```
<body>
<button onclick="fullscreen()">Click to go fullscreen</button>
</body>
```

Comment: a little googling would give you the answer easily.

Comment: I'm sorry, but many of the things I found online didn't work and I was confused as I'm only a beginner @TolgaEvcimen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this…

```
<script>
function fullscreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }
</script>
<button onclick="fullscreen()">Click to go fullscreen</button>
```